# set priority to script and css in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have built the tree view using third party javascript plugins. I have also use the web templates for my asp.net MVC 3 application. And use Layout view linking to lot of css and javascript.In my category view I want to display the tree view. But the due to script of layout view the tree view is interrupted and not displaying properly. When I put Layout = Null, it shows properly. How can I set priority to the link of script and css link for displaying tree view properly

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ClientDependancyMvc](http://nuget.org/packages/ClientDependency-Mvc/) NuGet package.
It allows to set priority to clientside resources like this:

```
Html.RequiresCss("Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css", "Content", 2);
Html.RequiresCss("Bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css", "Content", 3);

Html.RequiresJs("jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", "googleCDN", 1);
Html.RequiresJs("jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js", "googleCDN", 2);
```

Where the last parameter is priority of inserting element into page. More info [here](https://github.com/Shandem/ClientDependency/wiki).